# having issue's in asp.net using my checkboxes to unhide my dropdowns

Tags: jquery, asp.net

ok so essentially what I am trying to do is when you click on my check box for a class it unhides a drop down so that you can select a name out of it. here is the html and the j query code I am using

```
`<tbody>
      @foreach (var a in DropDownList.GetCourses)
               {
                                    <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <input id="coursecheck" type="checkbox" name="courseId" value="@a.Id"/></td>
                                    <td>@a.CourseName</td>

                                   <td class="hidden" id="teachlist" data-fts-conectionid="@a.Id">@Html.DropDownList("instructorId", DropDownList.GetInstructors)</td>
                             </tr>
                                }<tr>


                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
```

`
and here is the jquery that I've been trying to use for it i have been looking around the site and searching and trying different things but I just can't get it to work.

```
`//$('main').on('change', '#coursecheck', function () {
//    var $checkbox = $(this);
//    var $checkboxid = $checkbox.attr("value");
//    var $dropdowndata = $('#teachlist').attr('data-fts-connectionid');
//    var $connect = function() {
//        if ($checkboxid == $dropdowndata && $('#teachlist').hasClass("hidden")) {
//            $('#teachlist').removeClass("hidden");
//        } else if ($checkboxid == $dropdowndata && !$('#teachlist').hasClass("hidden"))
//            $('#teachlist').addClass("hidden");


//    };
//});
//$('#main').on('click', '#coursepopover', function() {
//    if ($('#coursecheck').is('checked')) {
//        $('#teachlist').removeClass("hidden");
//    } else {
//        $('#teachlist').addClass("hidden");
//    }
//});`
```

I know it is something simple that I am just missing but i just can't see it maybe another pair of eye's can though thank you in advance for any help if I figure it out I will be sure to post the code fix for it.

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason may be that you're creating multiple `<input>` checkboxes and `<td>` elements with the same Id, so when you do something like `$('#teachlist')` - an Id selector - you may run into troubles.

It may be worth assigning each `<input>` a unique Id like:

```
id='@("coursecheck_" + a.Id.ToString())'
```

And each `<td>` a unique Id like:

```
id='@("teachlist_" + a.Id.ToString())'
```

(My syntax may be a little off - sorry)

I like this way you're thinking about this guy:

```
$('#courseinstructors2').on('change', '#coursecheck'....
```

But I think it may be better if you, say, assigned each `<input>` a class like `<input class='courseCheckBox'` (as it should be OK/expected that more than one element has the same class) and change your selector it to:

```
$('.courseCheckBox').on('change', <function>....
```

So $('.courseCheckBox') matches all your check boxes and binds their `change` event to your function.

This may turn your `on()` to:

```
$('.courseCheckBox').on('change', function () {
    var clickedCheckBox = $(this);
    var clickedCheckBoxId = $(this).attr('id'); //Grab the Id, like coursecheck_<number>

    //Can do this because we know the Id formats are coursecheck_<number> and teachlist_<number>
    var tdToUnhideId = clickedCheckBoxId.replace("coursecheck", "teachlist");
    var tdToUnhideSelector = "#" + toToUnhideId; //Create the Id selector from the Id

    if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(tdToUnhideSelector).hasClass("hidden")) {
         //Show it
         $(tdToUnhideSelector).removeClass("hidden");
    } else {
        //Hide it
        $(tdToUnhideSelector).addClass("hidden");
    }
});
```

I have done a slight flip to your conditional where if the checkbox is checked `$(this).is(':checked')` and the `<td>` has the hidden class then unhide it, otherwise we hide it.

Not sure if that'll solve your issue or not, but hopefully it's seeded some stuff to get your started. Apologies in advance if it was not helpful.

Comment: so that worked wonderfully I new it was something way rediculas that I just wasn't seeing

Comment: Not a problem - that one's got me a few times as well. If you found the response helped, please mark your question as answered for the next person who has a similar problem to find :-)